# require 'icalendar' causes an error - even after I install the icalendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails. I need to use an iCalendar event in my web app.

First, I installed the iCalendar gem as below:

```
gem install icalendar
```

I then ran the `gem list` command, and it indicated the gem was installed. However, I can't actually use the gem anywhere.  If I do:

```
event = Icalendar::Event.new
```

I get the error that iCalendar is an uninitialized constant.

If I try to include iCalendar within a class as below:

```
require 'icalendar'
```

I get the error:

```
MissingSourceFile:  no such file to load -- icalendar
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add the gem to your Gemfile?

Comment: Which ruby version do you use (`ruby -v`)?

Comment: I am having same exact problem. What did you end up doing?

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to restart my rails server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the path to ruby on top of `/usr/bin/gem` match the output of `which ruby`? If not, make sure they match or give the explicit path to the one in `/usr/bin/gem`.

Answer (score 0):

In RoR you should put line `gem 'icalendar'` in your `Gemfile` - and Rails will require it for you.